# Ubuntu 20.04: "E: Package 'wine32' has no installation candidate"

Tags: wine

On a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04.1, I tried to install wine32 (`sudo apt-get install wine32`). However, there is an error: `E: Package 'wine32' has no installation candidate`. How can this be?

```
$ sudo apt-get update
  ...
$ sudo apt-get install wine32
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package wine32 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libwine

E: Package 'wine32' has no installation candidate
```

I need `wine32` to run a 32 bit Windows executable.

Comment: Shouldn't setting `WINEARCH` with regular wine be enough?

Comment: @muru `WINEARCH=win32 wine myprogram.exe` results in: `it looks like wine32 is missing, you should install it.
multiarch needs to be enabled first.  as root, please
execute "dpkg --add-architecture i386 && apt-get update &&
apt-get install wine32"
wine: WINEARCH set to win32 but '/home/user/.wine' is a 64-bit installation.`

Comment: Hmmm, in that case, `wine32` is in universe: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/wine32 you probably just need to enable it. Ah, no, it;s only available for the `i386` arch, not `amd64`.

Comment: @muru Okay, so I followed the instructions in the error message above: `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install wine32`. Now I get another error: `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine32:i386 : Depends: libwine:i386 (= 5.0-3ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Comment: Since I am unable to solve the problem on Ubuntu 20.04, I ended up installing Wine on 32-bit Debian 10 (buster) to run my 32-bit Windows executable. Recent Ubuntu LTS versions (18.04 and 20.04) have no 32-bit versions, so I went with 32-bit Debian instead.

Comment: Update: I have solved the problem. I ran `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` before trying to install wine32. This made the package versions consistent with each other, so that there are no conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

In my case: docker witch node, java, angular and electron this works - I left full dockerfile

```docker
FROM node:16.15.0

WORKDIR /work
COPY package.json .

RUN apt update
RUN apt-get -y install zip unzip

# node_modules witch angular and electron
RUN npm install -g n @angular/cli electron electron-builder

# JAVA
RUN apt-get -y install default-jre
RUN apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless 

# Wine (Wine32)
RUN apt install -y software-properties-common
RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386
RUN wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
RUN apt-key add winehq.key
RUN add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian/ buster main'
RUN apt update
RUN apt -y install --install-recommends winehq-stable

EXPOSE 3002
```